# Macros no longer working in VS2005

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2005, macros

I'm using VS2005 on Vista. I'm using some macros, but now they have suddenly stopped working. No error messages of any kind. I am not aware of having done anything that could trigger this.

- I have made sure that "Allow macros to run" is checked in Tools->Options->Addin/Macro Security.
- I have tried running the macros from a keyboard shortcut, from the Macro Explorer, and from the Macros IDE, all in vain: The little spinning icon displays shortly (<1 sec) and then disappears without the macro being executed.
- I have tried putting a breakpoint on the first line of the macro and then executing it from the main IDE, with no effect (the breakpoint isn't hit).
- I have tried the same from the Macro IDE: The state changes to "running", but the breakpoint isn't hit. I have to break the execution manually.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Back up your settings before trying this, but you can go to the the folder that devenv runs from, in a command window and try this command:

```
devenv /resetskippkgs
```

Here's a link on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241276%28VS.80%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the link, but unfortunately it didn't have any effect on the problem.